# SSL issue for database connection on Kubernetes

Tags: java, mysql, kubernetes, ssl, amazon-rds

I have an environment where SSL is enabled for the db connection with Amazon RDS MySQL, and I'm seeing the following exception when the application starts:
`Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)`

I have downloaded the pem file from the Amazon website, and used the following scripts to first create the truststore, then to upload the secret to the environments.

```
mydir= "/myproject/scripts/python/secrets/resources"
truststore=truststore.jks
storepassword=password

split -p "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" /myproject/scripts/python/secrets/resources/dev-certs/eucentral/eu-central-1-bundle.pem rds-ca-

for CERT in rds-ca-*; do
  alias=$(openssl x509 -noout -text -in $CERT | perl -ne 'next unless /Subject:/; s/.*(CN=|CN = )//; print')
  echo "Importing $alias"
  keytool -import -file ${CERT} -alias "${alias}" -storepass ${storepassword} -keystore ${truststore} -noprompt
  rm $CERT
done

echo "Trust store content is: "

keytool -list -v -keystore "$truststore" -storepass ${storepassword} | grep Alias | cut -d " " -f3- | while read alias 
do
   expiry=`keytool -list -v -keystore "$truststore" -storepass ${storepassword} -alias "${alias}" | grep Valid | perl -ne 'if(/until: (.*?)\n/) { print "$1\n"; }'`
   echo " Certificate ${alias} expires in '$expiry'" 
done
```

```
def create_certificate_secret(context, namespace, secret_name):
    certs = []
    path = 'resources/'

    if 'dev' in context:
        path = path + 'dev-certs/'

    eu_central_certs = ['truststore.jks', 'eu-central-1-bundle.pem']

    if 'eucentral' in context:
        path = path + 'eucentral/'
        certs = eu_central_certs

    statement = "kubectl --context " + context + " -n " + namespace + " create secret generic " + secret_name

    for cert in certs:
        statement = statement + " --from-file=" + cert + '=' + path + cert

    os.system(statement)
```

When I run the script, I can see that the secret gets created, and it has inside the pem file and the truststore, and that all the certificates from the pem were included in the truststore. The mountPath looks correct too, so I am wondering why the above configuration doesn't work.